# Django model, integers as choices

Tags: django, django-models

could you tell me if the following code is correct? I want to create a drop down that in the django admin will show a dropdown with a selection of integer:

```
class Test(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    Test specifications
    """
    TIME_INTERVALS = Choices(
        ('SECONDS_30', 30)
        ('SECONDS_60', 60)
        ('SECONDS_90', 90)
        ('SECONDS_120', 120)
        ('SECONDS_150', 150)
        ('SECONDS_300', 300)
    )

    sample_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TIME_INTERVALS, default=TIME_INTERVALS.SECONDS_30)
```

Thank you

Comment: Where does the `Choices` comes from? I think removing it would fix it from `TIME_INTERVALS` which will turn it into a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern is:

```py
# list of tuples:
INTEGER_CHOICES = (
  (<int>, <string>),
  ...
)
```

Where `<int>` is the value stored in the DB and `<string>` is what is displayed to users in the drop down menu

A typical use case is as follows:

**models.py**

```py
SECONDS_30 = 30
SECONDS_90 = 90
...

TIME_INTERVALS = (
    (SECONDS_30, "30 Seconds"),
    (SECONDS_90, "90 Seconds"), 
    ...
)

class Test(...):

    sample_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TIME_INTERVALS, ...)
    ...
```

Then in your views:

**views.py**

```py
from . import models

# update sample time:
test_instance = models.Test.objects.get(...)
test_instance.sample_time = models.SECONDS_30
test_instance.save()
...
```

Comment: A list of tuples would be `((<int>, <string>), ...)`. Your `TIME_INTERVALS` is a simple list.

Comment: This does not answer the question about admin.